# Generating a Unique ID in Google Sheets based on an Excel formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to rework this Excel formula for [Google Sheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sheets) and am getting stuck on where the formula parse is.

The formula in Excel is:

`=IF([@SCOPE]="","",'PROJECT OVERVIEW'!$B$1&"-"&VLOOKUP([@SCOPE],SCOPE_TABLE,2,FALSE)+(SUMPRODUCT($A$1:$A1=A2*1)+1)*0.01`)

It is meant to look up the "scope name" and add a unique identifieridentifier based on the Scope ID and, if there are multiple iterations of that Scope name and ID, then it changes the identifier sequentially.

Data Input:

[image: Data Input]

Exported Data:

[image: Exported Data]

I would like to adjust this to work in Google Sheets, but I am getting an error. I think it most likely has to do with how the formula is structured. Since I copied each sheet exactly along with the *Defined* names.

Comment: Re *"I am getting an error"*: Can you be more specific? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78090327/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general working translation of your Excel formula in sheets; *without the named ranges* of course since I do not have a general idea on how this part `[@SCOPE]` works in Excel.

This formula goes into **Cell_D2** of `ASSEMBLY ID`:

```js
=IF(A2="","",'PROJECT OVERVIEW'!$B$1&"-"&VLOOKUP(A2,'PROJECT OVERVIEW'!A$10:B,2,FALSE)+(SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A1=A2)*1)+1)*0.01)
```

Adjust the ranges within the formula to make sure they are pointing right within your sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! really helped me figure out how to rework my spreadsheet! I appreciate it!